# Notepad is saving xquery file with txt suffix

Tags: xml, xquery

Wikipedia says that XQuery can run through file extensions .xq, .xqy, .xquery. However, when I try to create a file with any of these extensions, Notepad rather creates an .xq.txt file and so on. Do I need to add any registry entries or something?

P.S. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use notepad at all to be honest.

Check this tutorial to see how to get started with an Eclipse based XQuery IDE: [XQuery.me](http://www.xquery.me/tutorial_xquery_get_started/get_tutorial_page/download_install_run_xquery).
Otherwise, I would use [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) instead of notepad.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Two possibilities:

- Just put some double quotes around your filename, and notepad will save it without adding .txt.
- Select "All Files" in the file content box will stop notepad adding .txt, too.

Better solution as stated before: use some better editor like Notepad++ or [e](http://www.e-texteditor.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is providing open-source plug-ins for XQuery. More at http://xqdt.org.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions for this:

1. While saving the name save it with "" . For example foo.xq will be "foo.xq"
2. Change the type of File to all Files. This will not save the file as .txt